# "Несёт в себе(,) словно тяжёлый груз." Обособлять ли сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

***Есть обиды и ошибки, которые он*** [человек] **несёт в себе(,) словно тяжёлый груз.**

Стоит обособить сравнительный оборот в данном предложении или всё же связь со сказуемым достаточно тесна, чтобы этого не делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть обиды и ошибки, которые он  несёт **в себе,  словно тяжёлый груз.**

Лучше обособить оборот.

С одной стороны, **это сравнительный оборот**,  а с другой стороны,  мы можем увидеть здесь **однородные отношения**: несёт в себе, несёт как тяжелый груз.